# How to configure map of List attribute in AutoMapper?

Tags: automapper

I'm pretty newbie to AutoMapper. I have four classes:

```cs
public class Source
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<SourceItem> items {get;set;}
}

public class SourceItem
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string firstName {get;set;}
   public string lastName {get;set;}
}

public class Destination
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<SourceItemDestination> items {get;set;}
}

public class SourceItemDestination
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string firstName {get;set;}
}
```

Is it possible to create a mapping profile to map Source to Destination **allowing to bring the list of SourceItemDestination when performing mapper.Map**?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: Have you checked the documentation or, search for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! Here are my classes:

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.EquivalencyExpression;
using Infrastructure.Data.Context;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using WebAPI.AutoMapper;

namespace WebAPI.Configurations
{
    public static class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void AddAutoMapperConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            if (services == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

            services.AddAutoMapper((serviceProvider, automapper) =>
            {
                automapper.AddCollectionMappers();
                automapper.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<CellLabDbContext>(serviceProvider);
            }, typeof(MappingProfile).Assembly);            
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using ApplicationCore.Domain;
using AutoMapper;
    
namespace WebAPI.AutoMapper
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<SourceItem, SourceItemDestination>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

**Important tip**: I had problems when mapping the lists because the property *items* of Source class were read only:

```cs
public class Source
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<SourceItem> items {get;}
}
```

By doing this the mapper does not map the list. However, it does not raise any error or warning.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/10.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#all-collections-are-mapped-by-default-even-if-they-have-no-setter